# Will method call in a interrupt exception catch finish the run() method and make the thread finished

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt

I have a thread with the following `run()` method.

I wrote this code to conclude a failure after 2 seconds and execute `startNewRound()` if no interrupt happens in that 2 seconds. If the thread is interrupted while `isLateToTimeout = true`, it should call `startNewRound()` and finish the execution so that the thread will be terminated. For any other interrupt, it should start waiting for 2 seconds again.

What I want to know is whether this thread will be terminated(as I have explained above) after `startNewRound()` call in the catch block.

```
public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        System.out.println("FAILURE"));
        startNewRound();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        if (isLateToTimeout){
            startNewRound();
        }
        else{
            run();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"whether this thread will be terminated after `startNewRound()` call"* There is no code after either `startNewRound()` call, so if `startNewRound()` returns normally, the `run()` method will return normally, all up through recursive calls if any, and the thread will end normally, so yeah, of course the thread will be "terminated", what else would it do?

Comment: Most likely result is a stackoverflow. Recursion in an exception handler is rather ... insane. Use a loop. And use `Thread.currentThread().interrupted()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @BoristheSpider's input, I came up with this solution for the run method.

```
public void run() {
    int i = 0;
    while(i<=200){
        if (i == 200){
            startNewRound();
            break;
        }
        else{
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                if (isLateToTimeout){
                    startNewRound();
                    break;
                }
                else{
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

Hope this is the solution to properly terminate the thread after both calls of  `startNewRound()` without causing stackOverflow.